# Sum of a floor function

Tags: sequences-and-series, ceiling-and-floor-functions, divisor-sum

I have the following function :

$$
f(x)= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left\lfloor {\frac{x+i}{n}}\right\rfloor
$$

I have to show that :

$\forall_{x}\in \mathbb{R}, f(x+1)=f(x)+1$

I proved that : $\forall x\in [0,1[$, $f(x)=0$, but I struggle finding something to do with it.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The "I proved that" part is not meant to help with what you are trying to show.  They are just two separate pieces of an induction proof.

Comment: Look for a way to simplify $f(x+1)-f(x)$.  It will help to see what's going on if you write out the terms of the summation (no need to evaluate the floor symbols) for, say, $n=5$ and $x=3.14$.  You will find that many terms cancel out.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that you can write $f(x+1)$ to look like something involving $f(x)$ by reindexing the sum and breaking it apart:$$f(x+1) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left\lfloor \frac{(x+1)+i}{n} \right\rfloor = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left\lfloor \frac{x+i}{n} \right\rfloor = \left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left\lfloor \frac{x+i}{n} \right\rfloor \right) + \left\lfloor \frac{x+n}{n} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{x+0}{n} \right\rfloor = f(x)+ \left\lfloor \frac{x}{n}+1 \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{x}{n} \right\rfloor = f(x)+1$$

Comment: Note: The last step uses the property that [real+integer]=[real]+integer.